# jquery-select2 send values to server as CSV string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, jquery-select2

Is it possible to send as one CSV-string all selected values in  HTML `select` element with `multiple="multiple"` using [jquery-select2](https://select2.github.io/) library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and could not find any options to accomplish this directly through the Select2 plugin. However, it was easy enough to create a separate input element and synch it on the select's change event.

```
var $options = $('select#options'),
    $optionscsv = $('input#optionscsv');

$options.select2()
  .on('change', function() {
    $optionscsv.val($options.val());
  });
```

Here's a live example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpLbLG